# IE 9 compresses white space within XML DOM

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer

I have a javascript routine that grabs an XML stream via AJAX and then parses it. It works fine in FF and Chrome but in IE 9, if there are consecutive Line Feeds within a node, IE compresses them into a space and one line feed.

Specifically, where retNode is an xml node, retNode.text has the compressed white space in IE, but includes all the characters in FF and Chrome.

I have tried writing my own routine to parse the XML, but that seems fragile and a waste of time. I tried using the PreserveWhitespace property, but that does not seem to be available in javascript. I tried using retNode.nodeValue instead of retNode.text, but nodeValue had no value.

I'd prefer a solution that does not use jquery because I don't know jquery, and I am not sure what other code I would need to add to make jquery work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should use `CDATA` or something, if you expect your whitespace to be preserved.  Can you modify this XML source?

Comment: In the general case, the treatment of whitespace in XML is up to the document grammar - the DTD or XSD. It's been too long since I looked at browser behavior in this area to provide an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`preserveWhiteSpace` is available in JavaScript.

Have you tried the following code?

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseXML.preserveWhiteSpace = true;
…
```

Comment: `preserveWhiteSpace` is indeed available from JavaScript on IE, but trying to access `xhr.responseXML` before establishing the connection will give the following error: `The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available`. According to @JoeFawcett, it used to be possible to call `xhr.responseXML.preserveWhiteSpace = true` with IE8 between  calling `open()` and `send()`, but doing so with IE9 returns the following error: `Could not complete the operation due to error c00c023f`.

Answer (score 0):

It should only be whitespace between tags that you are losing. Whitespace between non-tags (such as between strings within a pair of tags) should always be preserved.

In other words `<tag>     </tag>` will become `<tag></tag>` whereas `<tag>foo bar</tag>` will remain unaltered.

If you need whitespace between two tags to be preserved, and `preserveWhiteSpace` is not working for you for some reason, then I think you'll have to put `&#160;` in your XML source if possible (the numeric version of `&nbsp;` which you can't use as it's an illegal XML character under normal circumstances, i.e. unless you've defined the entity)

Comment: A plain space is different than a non-breakable space, so the solution you propose is not strictly equivalent to what the person who asked the question is attempting to do.